# Intentando eliminar un registro de una galería en PowerApps

Tags: app, microsoft, gallery, powerapps

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para el control de asistencia a un evento. Tengo un excel con los datos básicos de los asistentes a este y he creado un código qr específico para cada uno de ellos. Lo que tiene que hacer mi aplicación es escanear el código QR, comprobar a qué asistente pertenece y luego ir "tachando" de alguna manera las personas que ya han entrado al evento. Para ello he puesto una galería en la aplicación que muestra el listado de personas que tienen que asistir al evento. Mi idea es que, a medida que estas vayan entrando, ir eliminando su registro de la galería, de manera que aquí solo se muestren las que faltan por entrar, pero no consigo hacerlo.

La galería muestra los datos de mi tabla (Tabla1). He intentado simplemente borrar los registros de la tabla de datos original pero no me deja hacerlo ya que esta es de solo lectura (tampoco se cómo podría modificar esto).

También había probado a simplemente cambiar el color de los registros, con el siguiente código:

```
If(
    ThisItem.CodigoQR = filaSeleccionada.CodigoQR,
    Color1,
    Color2
)
```

pero obtengo error ya que no reconoce ThisItem como nada (pensaba que era una manera de "recorrer las filas", pero se ve que no). [filaSeleccionada es la fila correspondiente en la tabla de datos]

Alguna idea ? Gracias !!